# Creating keys without values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I want to create keys that have no values, just to have list of certain data for each user in my case. 
So it should look like something like that:

```
database
   |
  user_id6
    |____data1
    |____data2
```

In my example, each user should have a list of data, where the data is they key. Is it possible? Or I should just create a key with some arbitrary value for example:

```
database
   |
  user_id6
    |____data1: true
    |____data2: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Nodes in Realtime Database can't have "no value", otherwise they would cease to exist.  Assigning some boolean value, as you're showing, is one way to represent your data.